# Running dotnet ef without Visual Studio throws an exception

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a project that is a .NET Core console application with just a model and some seed data. On a development desktop I can go to the application directory, run `dotnet ef database update` and everything is fine (I need to copy `appsettings.json` to `bin\...` directory, but OK).

The problem is when I need to run this in the client environment (with VPN access, and without Visual Studio there). First, I am not sure what exactly I need to copy to the remote machine. But let's say, I copied the whole project. First, when I run, I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '.nuget\packages.tools\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools'.

I have a directory .nuget\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools but not under `.tools`. Out of despair I created .tools and copied this directory under it, but now I am getting the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.ProjectToolsCommandResolver. ResolveCommandSpecFromToolLibrary(LibraryRange toolLibraryRange, String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, ProjectContext projectContext)
>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.ProjectToolsCommandResolver. ResolveCommandSpecFromAllToolLibraries(IEnumerable`1 toolsLibraries, String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, ProjectContext projectContext)
>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.ProjectToolsCommandResolver. ResolveFromProjectTools(String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, String projectDirectory)
>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.ProjectToolsCommandResolver.Resolve (CommandResolverArguments commandResolverArguments)
>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.CompositeCommandResolver.Resolve (CommandResolverArguments commandResolverArguments)
>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.CommandResolver.TryResolveCommandSpec(String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, NuGetFramework framework, String configuration, String outputPath)
>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Create(String commandName, IEnumerable`1 args, NuGetFramework framework, String configuration, String outputPath)
>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
>   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)

Clearly, my trial and error attempts to find the right way hit a wall. Is there some substantive (not just syntax) documentation as to how to run EF Core commands outside Visual Studio? .NET is version 1.1 if that matters

Comment: Please post your `project.json` or your `.csproj`.

Comment: What is the version of EF are you using? Are you using project.json or csproj based solution?

Comment: EF Core 1.1. project.json. My error was that I didn't run `dotnet restore` (see comment below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have not removed Entity framework completly hence the error that path: `.nuget\packages.tools\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` is not found.

Somewhere in code there must be a reference to this file. If you are using project.json try checking your tools and depenedencies for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`.

If you are using the .csproj SDK version. Check your project file for any of these references and remove them.

Comment: *Of course*, there is a dependency on this package. Without that dependency `dotnet ef` wouldn't run at all. In Visual Studio I just go to NuGet Package Manager (screen or command line) and install it. The question was how to resolve the dependency; not to how to get rid of it. That said, your answer got me thinking... After I copied the project to remote server, rather than running `nuget install`, I ran `dotnet restore` and it installed **all** the packages in package.json. Since there is no *better* answer, I'll mark yours with thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry, then I miss understood you. You should post you comment and an answer and mark it as the answer :-). Thanks for posting your solution anyways :)